# Where to place humans.txt on Joomla

Tags: joomla

I made a webisite last year. Now I' am thinking of putting humans.txt on the website. For Joomla. I have placed the humans.txt on the templates folder which structure is like this

```
www.example.com/templates/custom/humans.txt
```

This doesn't work? Is there any specific location I should place the humans.txt. I don't want to use any plugins or extensions. Thanks!

Comment: You can't just dump a file in the file system and expect it to 'work'. You'll need to modify your system, either with a plugin, or by editing your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`humans.txt` is just a text file, it's not actually a browser or HTML feature et al.

As the [Humans TXT website](http://humanstxt.org) suggests the file should go in your website root directory (i.e. not in the Joomla `/templates` directory) "just next to the robots.txt file".

To "make `humans.txt` work" you will also need to add the relevant header to the pages served by Joomla.

If you want you can add an author tag to the  of the template, usually, by editing the templates `index.php` file. Which you will find in:

`/templates/mytemplate/index.php`

* *(Where "**mytemplate**" is the name of the template in use on your site.)*

To this file you will want to add something like this between the `<head>` tags.

`<link type="text/plain" rel="author" href="http://mydomain.com/humans.txt" />`

* *(replacing **mydomain.com** with your actual domain)*

Personally, this is probably easier done by searching the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org) and finding out which of the approximately 7500 extensions already do this, e.g. [NS HumansTXT](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/content-infos/credits/16942)